# Como criar um botão com o plugin Custom Scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Custom Scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

A minha idéia é criar apenas um botão. Ao clicar nele ele ficar ativado e com o scroll automático funcionando, ao clicar novamente ele ficar desativado e desabilita o scroll automático.

Comment: Você poderia dar mais detalhes?

Answer (score 1):

Cria o custom scroll para uma div:

$(".content").mCustomScrollbar({
    scrollInertia:150
});

Remove o custom scroll de uma div:

```
$('#remove-scroll').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".content").mCustomScrollbar("destroy");
});
```

Adiciona o custom scroll

```
$("#adiciona-scroll").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".content").mCustomScrollbar("update");
});
```

Re-cria o custom scroll

```
$("#recria-scroll").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".content").mCustomScrollbar({
        scrollButtons:{
            enable:true
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ficou um pouco confuso @VictorMendoça. Criei um JSFIDDLE e importei o css e o arquivo js do Custom Scrollbar, tente edita-lo  com sua logica? http://jsfiddle.net/jeffersonalison/4FTcU/1/

Comment: Fiz um fiddle, mas parece que o site do fonte deles está com pequeno bug no load dos javascripts. http://jsfiddle.net/vmendonca/CbfzT/

Dá uma olhada na página deles sobre remover/adicionas scrolls: http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/disable_destroy_example.html
 - 
Recomendo você baixar o plugin em sua máquina e testar com o código que te passei ;]

Comment: Hum.. pior que parece estar com problema mesmo. Mas Victor minha ideia é de criar apenas um botao.. ai quando estiver ativado o scroll automatico funciona, senão estiver ativado ele não funciona.